# Derivative over the function itself

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am new to calculus. Let $f(X)$ be continuous and differentiable over a set of variables $X$ where $x \in X$ and $x \in (0,\infty)$. Is there any general solution or rules to solve $\frac{f'(X)}{f(X)}$?

Comment: "Where $x\in X$ and $x \in (0,\infty)$" so $X=(0,\infty)$? Also do you mean $f(x)$?

Comment: What do you mean "solve $\frac{f'(X)}{f(X)}$"? This is not an equation, so I don't see what would constitute a solution.

Comment: If this is a probability density function, go ahead and add that tag.

Comment: $f$ is a function over multiple variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_i,\dots,x_n$ where $x_i \in X$. Sorry that I did not mean to solve $\frac{f'(X)}{f(X)}$. The question is "is there a general solution to $\frac{f'(X)}{f(X)}$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course if you can differentiate $f(x)$ you can immediately write $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$ by just dividing.  For example, if 
$$
f(x) = x^3 + 5 \\
f'(x) = 3x^2 \\
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{3x^2}{x^3+5}
$$
But I suspect what your professor or teacher is getting at is that it is sometimes easier if you realize that
$$
\frac{d(\log(f(x))}{dx} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
$$
For example, if
$$
f(x) = e^{\sin x}\\ \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \cos x
$$
without much work, since $\log\left( e^{\sin x} \right)= \sin x$.

Comment: A typo: **since $\log\left( e^{\sin x} \right)= \cos x$** should read **since $\log\left( e^{\sin x} \right)= \sin x$**

Comment: Is there a general solution to this problem? By the way is there a term for the expression $\frac{f'(X)}{f(X)}$?